# How to create a Metro WSIT client out of an given WSDL (created in Axis2) in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-axis, java-metro-framework, wsit

I have a WSDL file which was generated by Axis 2 and declares security policies:

I followed the tutorials on the metro site to generate a Web Service Client in netbeans out of the WSDL. The tutorial says to edit the Web Service Attributes in order to declare KeyStore and etc. But in my case I cannot edit any Security options only Transport options.

Can anybody help me with this problem? Would it be better to use Axis2 for the Client? How difficult is that? For the secured communication we will use a keystore.

The WSDL file:

```
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:InitiatorToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:X509Token>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <sp:RecipientToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:X509Token>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:RecipientToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Strict/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                        <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <sp:Policy>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                    </sp:Policy>
                </sp:Wss10>
                <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <sp:Body/>
                </sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <sp:Body/>
                </sp:EncryptedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
```